# Git checkout to remote branch

Tags: git

I want to switch to the remote branch in Git.
What is the difference these commands?

`git checkout -b feature1 origin/feature1` and

`git checkout --track origin/feature1`

Comment: FYI - in recent versions of Git, you can simply `git checkout feature1` and (assuming you don't have a local branch named `feature1`) Git will correctly guess you want a new local branch called `feature1` which tracks `origin/feature1`.

Answer (score 2):

Those do the same thing, creating a local branch called `feature1` starting at the current position of `origin/feature1`, and tracking origin's feature1 branch (i.e. it knows where to pull from). This can generally be understood from the manpage, under `--track`:

> If no `-b` option is given, the name of the new branch will be derived from the remote-tracking branch. ... This would tell us to use "hack" as the local branch when branching off of "origin/hack" ...

I believe that in older versions of Git the second one might not have worked, but unless that's important to you, you can just not worry about it. There have been a lot of miscellaneous "do what I mean" improvements to the UI over the years.